# change month/day to day/month

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a column of registration times, the format of which is:

month/day/year hour:minute

I need to change it to:

day/month/year hour:minute

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check for example `?as.POSIXct`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1157/date-and-time#t=201702081014117781585

Answer (score 1):

You can use format function to format your registration time

format(RegistrationTime, "%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M")